# Visual Studio custom shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Can we use custom shortcuts in Visual Studio ? I want to insert some code on a shortcut key press. for example, I need to insert a line-break `<br/>` on a shortcut press.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For VS2010 at least the solution is to use a [macro](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/02/creating-and-using-a-macro-vstipenv0055.aspx). Once your macro is created see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/07/create-a-shortcut-key-for-a-macro-vstiptool0066.aspx) for information on how to bind it to a shortcut key.

I don't have VS2012 available to confirm but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12062515/137001), the macro recording facility has been removed. There are some solutions posted in that question which might help.