# SHIFT + ENTER VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to find anywhere that I can achieve this. I simply want to setup a macro like in sublime text or atom where I can hit `shift+enter` and it will go to the end of the line, add a semicolon, and bring me to the next line. I've just started `C` development and trying to use `vs2013` and not having this is pretty much going to send me sprinting back to sublime text, intellisense isn't worth destroying my workflow.

I've tried: `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Text Editor : Shift + Enter > Edit.Breakline` As suggested by someone in a vs2010 thread but that proved fruitless.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: fruitless as in nothing worked or only did part of what you were wanting?

Comment: Fruitless as in it just continued the standard shift+enter behavior of moving the cursor and everything after it to the next line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013

Comment: While I hope you get your answer, you may be underestimating the value of Intellisense.

Comment: That post by Steve probably answers this, but just for the record, shift+enter already has a meaning in VS, so I doubt it would have let you use that anyway.

Comment: Well, back to a text editor I guess. Sort of sad, I liked VS but removing macros is pretty insane, IMO. Their data said otherwise, so that's that. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

The command is **Edit.LineOpenBelow**. It's already assigned to **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

I had the same issue, so I swapped the commands for **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and **Shift+Enter**.

**Shift+Enter** is assigned to **Edit.BreakLine** by default.