# Microsoft Visual Studio: how to make one-click release builds without leaving debug mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I program in C#. The specifics of my development process is that i often **run** an application in debug mode, but sometimes I need to quickly **build**  (without running) a dll / exe in release mode.

Now i have to click to dropdown menu, change debug > release, wait for 5-10 seconds while Studio is loading something and only then click "Build". Then change back release > debug and wait again. This is pretty annoying.

Tell me please how to achieve one-click release builds without leaving debug mode?

Comment: You can normally change the active configuration with a combobox on the toolbar.  Can't see it, the menu is covering it up.

Comment: Build using command line? Take a look at `msbuild`

Comment: I've tried to use command line, and it is works. But it has two disadvantages: 1. Build happens outside Visual Studio window, its output goes to console/log, it is less convinient. 2. I have to copy build .bat script for each new project manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a new button if you don't see one now. Here's how.
Follow these menu paths(?).

```
TOOLS > CUSTOMIZE >
```

In the **toolbar** tab, create a new toolbar. Give a name you like.
Select **commands** tab, select **toolbar** option (radio) button, and select your new toolbar from the combo.
Click **add command**, select **build** from the list at left.
From the right side list, add **Build solution** and **Solution Configurations** respectively.

Enjoy. :) But not 1 click.

P.S.: You'll see your new toolbar with a build button.

Edit:
Visual Studio currently does not support macro recording. [Can I record/play macros in Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013)
So either creating an add-in or using something like http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/ may fix your problem. (Didn't work for me.)

Comment: But this button will use the same mode (debug/release) as is in the drop-down menu, won't it?

Comment: @DoctorCoder
Sure. 3 Clicks.  
But better than Build > Configuration Manager > Release > Close  
Build > Build Solution

Answer (score 0):

You can build any configuration from the Visual Studio [Batch Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/169az28z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) dialog. It is not one click, but may simplify your workflow.