# Macros with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-macros

I downloaded the free version of Visual Studio 2015. It is called Visual Studio Community 2015. It is said that it is the full version. But I don't see macros. So I tried installing an extension from  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e2103b6-87cf-4fef-9410-a580c434b602.

That says it is "Text Macros for Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015" so it should work on 2015. But it doesn't.

I'm wondering if Visual Studio Community 2015 is more like Express in that is not full featured.

So I tried Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 thinking it would give me a free license (since I'm just an individual). But even though it says it installed a license, it still says it will expire in 90 days.

1. Does anyone know how to use Macros in Visual Studio Community 2015
2. Does anyone know how to get a full version of VS2015 with a free license (which so many people claim is possible)?

Comment: If you mean keyboard macros, they were removed Visual Studio 2012. No edition of Visual Studio has them.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/VS-Macros-are-back

Comment: RE: removing keyboard macros in the first place, they have a team over there tasked with basically just thinking up bad ideas, right?

Answer (score 0):

They are now available in VS 2013 and 2015 but you need to add the Microsoft Macros add-in. I'm still playing with it. But you do get the macros explorer and can record and replay. I'm still having trouble assigning a keyboard shortcut beyond the standard 9 shortcuts they give you. But macros are there, thank goodness.

I've been using VS Community since 2013 and never had any license required. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you're a student you can probably get it from DreamSpark.

Comment: I'm not a student... I'm a retired firmware engineer. Do you know if VS2015 Community is a "full" version?